# percentage python code for data analysis using pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, percentage

I want to write Python code to analyze the percentage of `m_tax` and `m_tan`   for Python 2.7 from the web page (http://owww.met.hu/eghajlat/eghajlati_adatsorok/bp/Navig/202_EN.htm). I have already the dataframe code, but I couldn't write percentage code. Could somebody please help me how I can write the code. Thanks!

```
    datum  m_ta m_tax     m_taxd m_tan     m_tand
------- ----- ----- ---------- ----- ----------
1901-01  -4.7   5.0 1901-01-23 -12.2 1901-01-10
1901-02  -2.1   3.5 1901-02-06  -7.9 1901-02-15
1901-03   5.8  13.5 1901-03-20   0.6 1901-03-01
1901-04  11.6  18.2 1901-04-10   7.4 1901-04-23
1901-05  16.8  22.5 1901-05-31  12.2 1901-05-05
1901-06  21.0  24.8 1901-06-03  14.6 1901-06-17
1901-07  22.4  27.4 1901-07-30  16.9 1901-07-04
1901-08  20.7  25.9 1901-08-01  14.7 1901-08-29
```

Comment: Please define how these percentages should be calculated and show the desired df

Comment: @EdChum.. that was my trouble, it took me many times to think  but nothing I did.

Comment: I'm not asking you to provide code, just explain how these percentages should be calculated, are they simply divided by total or are they calculated using some other method or criteria

Comment: @EdChum.. here I want to give analysis based on percentage for comparison. I think they are simply divided by total. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html#pandas.Series.div) and pass the [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas.Series.sum) of the columns to add `%` columns:

```
In [66]:
df['m_tax%'],df['m_tan%'] = df['m_tax'].div(df['m_tax'].sum()) * 100, df['m_tan'].div(df['m_tax'].sum()) * 100
df

Out[66]:
     datum  m_ta  m_tax      m_taxd  m_tan      m_tand     m_tax%     m_tan%
0  1901-01  -4.7    5.0  1901-01-23  -12.2  1901-01-10   3.551136  -8.664773
1  1901-02  -2.1    3.5  1901-02-06   -7.9  1901-02-15   2.485795  -5.610795
2  1901-03   5.8   13.5  1901-03-20    0.6  1901-03-01   9.588068   0.426136
3  1901-04  11.6   18.2  1901-04-10    7.4  1901-04-23  12.926136   5.255682
4  1901-05  16.8   22.5  1901-05-31   12.2  1901-05-05  15.980114   8.664773
5  1901-06  21.0   24.8  1901-06-03   14.6  1901-06-17  17.613636  10.369318
6  1901-07  22.4   27.4  1901-07-30   16.9  1901-07-04  19.460227  12.002841
7  1901-08  20.7   25.9  1901-08-01   14.7  1901-08-29  18.394886  10.440341
```